# How to create an ".app" from python with Nuitka on Mac

Tags: python, software-distribution, nuitka

First time trying Nuitka, on macOS (10.14).

I did `python3 -m nuitka --standalone hello.py` (also tried with `--clang`)

The result is a weird `hello.dist` folder – which doesn't even appear as a folder in Finder – which contains a bunch of `.so` files, `Python` and my executable `hello`.

I thought it would create an `.app` bundle? Is there another step?

(I also tried https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus but that doesn't really compile the python.)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`python3 -m nuitka --standalone --macos-create-app-bundle hello.py`

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32569861)

Comment: It's a brilliant answer. What is wrong with straight to the point 1-line?